# Find the solution of the differential equation that satisfies the given initial condition

Tags: calculus

Find the solution of the differential equation that satisfies the given initial condition

$$xy' + y = y^2\;\; ;\;\;   y(1) = −5$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $\frac{y^\prime}{y^2-y} = \frac{1}{x}$, now try integrating both sides with respect to $x$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that

$$xy'+y=y^2$$ can be written as 
$$(xy)'=y^2$$

Let $xy=u$. Then $y^2=x^{-2}u^2$ and the equation becomes

$$u'=x^{-2}u^2$$

$$\frac{u'}{u^2}=x^{-2}$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $x\frac{dy}{dx} + y = y^2$.

Comment: You just rewrote the OPs equation. How is that a hint?

Comment: I assumed that this question is from an intro DE or calculus class, and I know my problem in those classes was looking at things the wrong way.

Comment: OK, but how do you know the OP is looking it "the wrong way"? How does writing $dy/dx$ instead of $y'$ help?

Comment: Looks like it's been a while since I've looked at these. I just assumed it was a separable DE. Well, time to review.

Comment: It is. That would be nice to write in the post.

Answer (score 0):

Divide through by $y^2$:

$$x \frac{y'}{y^2} + \frac{1}{y} = 1$$

which is equivalent to

$$-x \frac{d}{dx} \frac{1}{y} + \frac{1}{y} = 1$$

Let $u=1/y$:

$$u' - \frac{1}{x} u = -\frac{1}{x}$$

Determine an integrating factor; multiply through by $1/x$:

$$\frac{1}{x} u' - \frac{1}{x^2} u = -\frac{1}{x^2}$$

which may be reduced to

$$\frac{d}{dx} \frac{u}{x} = -\frac{1}{x^2}$$

which has solution

$$u(x) = 1+ C x$$

where $C$ is a constant of integration; this means that

$$y(x) = \frac{1}{1+C x}$$

Use your initial condition $y(1)=-5$ to find $C$:

$$-\frac{1}{5} = 1+C \implies C=-\frac{6}{5}$$